# Django API header cannot be fetched

Tags: python, django

Frontend is sending POST request with code and then I want to return qr code and a token. When I try to fetch 'token' header it returns none

```
@api_view(['POST'])
@csrf_exempt
def Create_new_doc(request):
   
    code = json.loads(request.body)
    code = code['code']

    characters = string.ascii_letters + string.digits
    token = ''.join(random.choice(characters) for _ in range(20))

    generate_qr_code.generate_qr(token)

    image_path = f"/files/qr_{token}.jpg"
    image_file = open(image_path, 'rb')

    response = FileResponse(image_file, content_type='image/jpeg')

    response['token'] = token
    response.status_code = 200

    return response
```

This is frontend part - getting image url works just fine

```
 fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/create-new', requestOptions)
                   .then((response) => {
                    if (response.ok) {
                        return response.blob().then((blob) => {
                        var tokeN = response.headers.get('token');
                        console.log(response.headers.get('token'))
                        console.log('Token:', tokeN);

                        const imageUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                        console.log('Image URL:', imageUrl);

                        return { tokeN, imageUrl };
                        });
                    }
```

Yeah, literary have no idea why it does not  work

Comment: And why are you attaching `token` to response dict instead of its headers then?

Comment: @SUTerliakov-supportsstrike  I mean that's the way you can add new value to header? if iI print ```print(response.headers)``` it will return the token and it's value

Comment: After further testing -  backend sworks just fine this is issue with frontend